# How do I host only one file using python

Tags: python, html, webserver

If I use the following code:

```
python3 -m http.server 8001
```

I have a page that hosts all files in that directory but I was wondering how I can host just a single file, and is there a way to make that file accessible with an html  tag. Thank you.

Comment: Put this file in some directory and use `python3 -m http.server 8001 -d /dir_name/`

Comment: Could this file be used in an html a tag as if going to a new page in a website. Thanks

Comment: Like this `<a href="http://localhost:8001">Home</a>`?